# Implement UIScrollview swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

My project's structure is this:
-View
--UIScrollView
---View
----containerItems

I'm trying to make my screen scrollable but always is static, this is my code:

```
class LoginCtrl: UIViewController {
    let svPantalla: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        sv.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 31, g: 90, b: 161)
        sv.contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        sv.isScrollEnabled = true
        sv.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return sv
    }()
    let v2: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
    //contenedor textField
    let contenedorCampos: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 255, g: 255, b: 255)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return view
    }()
    let botonLoginRegistrarme: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 255, g: 152, b: 0)
        button.setTitle("Iniciar Sesion", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(svPantalla)
        svPantalla.addSubview(v2)
        v2.addSubview(contenedorCampos)
        v2.addSubview(botonLoginRegistrarme)
        setear_posicion_svPantalla()
        setear_posicion_hijoV()
        setear_posicion_contenedor()
        setear_posicion_botonRegistrarme()
        //this functions are in the image added
    }
}
```

[image: functions]
My scroll is not working, how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you actually see your scrollview?

Comment: you have to set constraints in your scroll children for height, then the scroll view will calc its contentSize to make it scrollable. You can also try to set it manually but never tried. In your viewDidLoad put  `svPantalla.contentSize = CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)`

Comment: no @JohnnyAW but the backgroundcolor I can see

Comment: @GIJOW I put that and my scrollView appears but does not scroll the screen is static

Comment: Without constraints it will be hard to achieve

Comment: @GIJOW can you give me a piece of code about the constraints?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523131/adding-constraints-programmatically-in-uiscrollview-with-dynamic-buttons-swift

Comment: @GIJOW I added the constraints but I have same error

Comment: The problem still lying in your constraints and contentSize. Scroll views are easy to work but there are some pitfalls in those two aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set

> sv.contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)

Please remove this line or add value instead of 0.